# Performance difference between map<"string",..> and map<int,..>?

Tags: c++, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cost of using std::map with std::string keys vs int keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842979/cost-of-using-stdmap-with-stdstring-keys-vs-int-keys)

if I have the two pieces of code:

1#:

```
map<unsigned int, unsigned short> ConnectedIPs;

PLUGIN_EXPORT bool PLUGIN_CALL OnPlayerConnect(int playerid)
{
    PlayerLoopList.push_back(playerid);
    char szIP[32];
    GetPlayerIp(playerid,szIP);
    unsigned short explodeIP[4];
    sscanf(szIP, " %d[^.].%d[^.].%d[^.].%d", &explodeIP[0], &explodeIP[1], &explodeIP[2], &explodeIP[3]);
    g_PlayerIP[playerid] = (explodeIP[0] + (explodeIP[1] << 8) + (explodeIP[2] << 16) + (explodeIP[3] << 24));
    ConnectedIPs[g_PlayerIP[playerid]] += 1;
    if(ConnectedIPs[g_PlayerIP[playerid]] >= g_max_ip)
    {
        Report(playerid,CHECK_IPFLOOD);
    }
    return true;
}
```

2#:

```
map<char*, unsigned short> ConnectedIPs;//edited from char to char*

PLUGIN_EXPORT bool PLUGIN_CALL OnPlayerConnect(int playerid)
{
    PlayerLoopList.push_back(playerid);
    char szIP[32];
    GetPlayerIp(playerid,szIP);
    ConnectedIPs[szIP] += 1;
    if(ConnectedIPs[szIP] >= g_max_ip)
    {
        Report(playerid,CHECK_IPFLOOD);
    }
    return true;
}
```

would 2# be faster?
This code is for counting the amount of connected players fron one ip. I think I am doing it right, or I'm not?

Comment: ah ye it needs to be an array xd

Comment: I'm tempted to say the first would be faster if there were no optimizations along the way, but that both are the same speed in reality, and that isn't the bottleneck in the code.

Comment: Unless map lookups are a huge fraction of what you're doing, there's no practical difference.  Do ten million lookups and the string key might take an extra tenth of a second. (Yes, I made that number up).  Try it.

Comment: well if it's that then I think I can go for #1 as it's less memory-hungry :] no time difference = go for less memory usage

Comment: As a non-C++ programmer, does `unsigned short explodeIP[4]` create an array of 4 elements or 5?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant `map<string, unsigned short>` for the second case, otherwise it won't even compile.

Both trigger an *O(log n)* lookup in the map based on comparisons of keys. Comparing 32 bit integers is generally faster than comparing strings, so the first case should be faster.

I wouldn't worry about it though, unless there's profiling data showing this to have a significant impact on performance. If you do that only when the player connects, and the session tends to last "long enough", chances are this would be an insignificant optimization - and even then, switching to `unordered_map` will probably be more significant than changing the type of the key.

Comment: Using a hashtable/hashmap based alternative like `unordered_map` will allow near constant-time look up.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest effect is probably caused by the *size* of `std::string`. Your CPU cache can fit many more `long`s than `std::string`s.

However, I'd still choose the second option. That will work with IPv6.