# STL map<string,FOO> vs map<int,FOO> Performance

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

we know some compare function is used when inserting a new key.
which one is faster while accessing some key?
how much faster?
thanks

Comment: Why don't you just run some tests?

Comment: Usually, `int` key comparison is faster than `string`

Comment: Well, a string can hold way more information than a single int, which means there can be way more information to compare in determining whether one string is lexicographically less than another one, as opposed to a straight comparison between two ints.

Comment: possible duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462981/performance-difference-between-mapstring-and-mapint) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842979/cost-of-using-stdmap-with-stdstring-keys-vs-int-keys)

Answer (score 2):

STL map is comparison based as it is based on a search tree internally. That means that a number of key comparisons are performed when inserting or search elements. Comparisons of integers can be performed in constant time. Comparisons of strings depend on the lengths of the strings and *usually* take longer.