# Implement weighted graph

Tags: c++, graph

Say I have the following adjacency matrix:

```
  A B C D
A 0 9 0 5
B 9 0 0 0 
C 0 0 0 2
D 5 0 2 0
```

How would this acutally be implemented? I realize I can use a 2D array to represent the weighted edges between vertices but I'm not sure how to represent the vertices.

```
int edges[4][4];
string vertices[4];
```

Is this the way to do it? The index in the vertices array corresponds to the row index in the edges array.

Comment: yes, if you want to give them a "name", `string vertices[4]` suits. But I prefer to go with index numbers rather than names.

Comment: The vertices are represented inherently in the matrix. If you mean that you want to have proper names for your vertices, then yes, maintain separate strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a two dimensional `std::map`

Using this method allows for the matrix to grow and shrink when ever you want.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>> vertices;

    vertices["A"]["A"] = 0; vertices["A"]["B"] = 9; vertices["A"]["C"] = 0; vertices["A"]["D"] = 5;
    vertices["B"]["A"] = 9; vertices["B"]["B"] = 0; vertices["B"]["C"] = 0; vertices["B"]["D"] = 0;
    vertices["C"]["A"] = 0; vertices["C"]["B"] = 0; vertices["C"]["C"] = 0; vertices["C"]["D"] = 2;
    vertices["D"]["A"] = 5; vertices["D"]["B"] = 0; vertices["D"]["C"] = 2; vertices["D"]["D"] = 0;

    std::cout << vertices["A"]["A"] << std::endl;
    std::cout << vertices["A"]["B"] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use string instead of char (forcing string comparisons rather than single-character comparisons)? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842979/cost-of-using-stdmap-with-stdstring-keys-vs-int-keys

Comment: @statueuphemism That can be used too, I only used string because I didn't know if the OP also wanted multi character indexes. Besides, if you're programming for a modern computer and it ever comes to a crawl because you used a string than a char then you might want to consider getting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the indexes of adjacency matrix as vertices is common practice.

Comment: I realize that, but in my case I need the vertices to have separate names.

Answer (score 0):

If there are a fixed number of vertices in the graph. You could declare the vertices as an enum and index the array directly using the enumerated vertex names. I think it makes the mapping a little clearer.

```
enum VERTEX
{
    A = 0,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    LAST = D
};

int edge[LAST+1][LAST+1];
edge[A][A] = 0;
edge[A][B] = edge[B][A] = 9;
edge[A][C] = edge[C][A] = 0;
// etc.
```

This keeps things simple and quick by allowing you to use an array without any look-up penalty while keeping things easy to understand.

Answer (score -1):

For most intents and purposes it's usually more efficient to represent the graph as an adjentacy list:

```
std::vector< std::list<int> > graph;
```

So graph[i] is all neighboring vertexes of i. The advantage being that when dealing with graphs we usually want to traverse i's neighbors. Also, for large sparse graphs, space complexity is much lower. This of course could also be extended to include weights with something like:

```
std::vector< std::list<std::pair< int, int> > > graph;
```

or for more complex types, define a type Vertex...

EDIT: If you require indices as strings, this could easily be done by opting to std::map instead of std::vector:

```
std::map< std::string, std::list<std::pair< std::string /*vertex*/, int/*weight*/> > > graph;
```

But it appears from your original post that you just wish to map indexes to vertex names, in which case I'd go with the first soluion but also keep the vertex name mapped to the index:

```
std::vector< std::pair< std::string/*name*/, std::list<std::pair< int /*index*/, int/*weight*/> > > > graph;
```

Comment: How do you then access the second element? with your way the only way I can think of is using iterators

Comment: What do you mean by second element? what is the problem with using iterators?

Comment: Iterators are fine, I just personally wouldn't want to go through each element until I find the one I want in this case. I would prefer if that was abstracted away for me.

Comment: thank my lucky stars then that map has operator[] overloading and find function

Comment: That is true, but once again I'm taking about the second container which is a list that has an std::pair. The only way to use the operator[] on that is if you know both the index and the key.

Comment: Besides, if you look at the OP's original code you'll see that he is using arrays, which of course means integers are the actual indexes. The vertices array just maps indices to strings or vertex names

Comment: Like I said in my answer, this solution is built around the concept that usually we want to traverse ALL the vertex's neighbors. So iterating with iterators, std::for_each or BOOST_FOREACH is acceptable under that assumption. If this is not the case, then a 2d array may be preferable. I've seen very little cases in which graphs were the proper representation of a problem and this DS wasn't more suitable